# OpenCV JNI: Java/native handling of Mat - possibility for delete getting called twice?

Tags: java, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

I'm working on a project where I have a Mat that is allocated on the heap in native code (at the request of some Java code), like so:

```cpp
Mat* mat = new Mat(height, width, type, pointer_to_some_native_data_buffer);
```

I then create a Mat object in Java, and point it to that native Mat by using a pointer returned from native code:

```java
Mat javaHandleToNativeMat = new Mat(pointerFromNativeCode);
```

After doing some processing on it from the Java side, I call a native method to free the Mat that was allocated at the beginning:

```cpp
delete (Mat*) ptr;
```

My question is, could native memory corruption happen when the GC runs the finalizer method on the Java Mat that pointed to the native Mat?

The finalizer code is as follows:

```java
    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        n_delete(nativeObj);
        super.finalize();
    }
```

Notice that it calls `n_delete(nativeObj)`. I'm wondering if this could be a problem, since I previously deleted the object in native code. If it is a problem, what is the best way to fix the problem? Should I simply call `release()` on the native Mat, and allow it to actually be deleted in the finalizer when the GC runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're deleting the native `Mat` and the implementation of `n_delete` is:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1delete
  (JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong self)
{
    delete (Mat*) self;
}
```

the GC will delete the `cv::Mat` pointer twice, which is BAD. You can find [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#double-delete-disaster) a more in depth description on what deleting a pointer twice implies.

Comment: Hmm, it's not that *I* am overriding the finalizer, it's that the OpenCV Mat class already does. So I would have to extend that class and then override the already overridden finalizer, (and hopefully that finalizer wouldn't be declared as `final`, I'll have to check that)

Comment: @You'reAGitForNotUsingGit, I edited the answer after finding the correct documentation, this should be more correct.

Comment: So this tells me that the OpenCV Mat class needs to set a boolean flag in the constructor that takes a pointer to prevent calling `n_delete()` in the finalizer probably.

Comment: My advise is still not to delete the native Mat manually, and let the GC do that.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to award your answer the bounty. I thought that when the timer expired it automatically went to the highest voted answer unless you manually selected a specific one??

Comment: Not sure. I just hope the answer helped though ;)